# Using mouse event callbacks within Python classes

Tags: python, opencv, callback

I'd like to write a program that in its simplest form opens a window showing a webcam capture using OpenCV and printing the coordinates of the mouse cursor hovering over the window in terminal. For this i want to use a callback function. My problem is that this callback function does not seem to run. I do not get any error messages when running the program, but nothing seem to happen when I hover my cursor over the camera window.

I suspect that the cause for this might be that my callback function is in the class CallBack, and that cv.SetMouseCallback cannot access it or something. I am new to both OpenCV and callback functions, so any suggestions on what my problem might be or what I'm missing here would be appreciated.

My simplified code is shown below for reference. Thanks in advance.

```
import cv

class CallBack:

    def __init__(self):
        cv.NamedWindow("Camera", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        self.capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

    def on_mouse(self,event, x, y, flag, param):
        if(event == cv.CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE):
            print param
            print x,y

    def callback(self):
        while True:
            src = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
            s = "Hello World"
            cv.SetMouseCallback("Camera",self.on_mouse, param = s)
            cv.ShowImage("Camera", src)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cb = CallBack()
    cb.callback()
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, it won't do anything at all, because _everything_, even the `if __name__` part, is inside the `class` definition. Is that correct?

Comment: Side notes: (1) Always create new-style classes (`class CallBack(object):`). (2) Don't put extra parens around things like `if` conditions; it throws off experienced Python readers and makes them wonder why you thought it was necessary (is there some operator precedence that needs to be overridden? or a tuple or genexp? or …).

Comment: Also, how do you know that it's not calling `on_mouse`? You only `print` anything inside the `if`. What if the problem is that you've got the params wrong, or the `event` isn't what you expected? It would look exactly the same as not calling your code at all, right?

Comment: Finally: "I suspect that the cause for this might be that my callback function is in the class CallBack, and that cv.SetMouseCallback cannot access it or something." Nope, that's not it. When you do `self.on_mouse`, that gives you a bound method, which anyone (including `cv.SetMouseCallback`) can just treat as a `callable` and call. It doesn't need any special access. (And even if it did, all methods are "public" in Python, so that wouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: One more thing: Are you sure the camera window is active/focused/whatever-the-appropriate-term-is-for-your-platform? Often background windows don't get mouse events unless they do something special, and it's reasonable that OpenCV might not do that something special. (Sorry I can't be more specific, but I don't know what platform you're on.)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the feedback. First off: the `if __name___` part should not be inside the class, it just ended up that way when i formatted my question. I have edited it now. Also, I have tried a printout outside if the if-statement in the callback-function. It didn't print that either, so I'm quite sure the function isn't run. And I am also sure that my camera window is active as I repeatedly try to click inside of it. One final note is that the script seems to run as it should if the functions are not inside a class. This made me suspect the inaccessability of `self.on_mouse`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you're calling `SetMouseCallback` each time through the event loop? I'm not sure _why_ that would cause this, but it's not _inconceivable. (For example, maybe `SetMouseCallback` creates a new queue of mouse events to deliver to your callback, throwing out any existing queue.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the reason for this behavior. Turns out I have to add a

```
if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
    break
```

at the end of the while-loop. The reason seems to be (from what I have found) that the loop will now wait for 10 milliseconds for the escape-key to be pressed. If the escape-key is not pressed during this time, the loop will continue, `cv.SetMouseCallback` is called and `self.on_mouse` will run as it should. If the `cv.WaitKey()` is *not* called at the end of the while-loop, the program will get stuck in the `cv.ShowImage`-call, never call `cv.SetMouseCallback` and thus never execute `self.on_mouse`.

The updated simplified code will be as shown below.

```
import cv

class CallBack:

    def __init__(self):
        cv.NamedWindow("Camera", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        self.capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

    def on_mouse(self,event, x, y, flag, param):
        if(event == cv.CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE):
           print param
           print x,y

    def callback(self):
        while True:
             src = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
             s = "Hello World"
             cv.SetMouseCallback("Camera",self.on_mouse, param = s)
             cv.ShowImage("Camera", src)

             if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
                  break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cb = CallBack()
    cb.callback()
```

Refer to [this page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/c/highgui/WaitKey) for more information.